AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling Flatten.call(). 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
I'm trying to load a CNN model. But I can't do that. It said that
AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling Flatten.call().

'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Arguments received by Flatten.call():
  • args=(['<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 2048), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_644>'],)
  • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>

The condition is that I did CNN modelling for the CIFAR10 dataset, then  saved the JSON model. In the other block code, I want to load the model but have an error like that. What should I do?
I want my code to load the model (json format).

Do you have a minimum reproducible example?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
